# How can I reduce the number of layers of pattern matches?

Tags: f#

How can I reduce the number of layers of pattern matches?

Now there are 3 layers of nested pattern matches, which I think is a lot of repeated work.
I want to reduce it to 1 pattern match, is it possible? How to do it?

```ml
type test4 = {
    C: int option
} 
type test3 = {
    B: test4 option
}
type test2 = {
    A: test3 option 
}


let testANone = {
    A=None
}

let testBNone = {
    A=Some {
        B=None
    }
}
let testCNone ={
    A=Some {
        B=Some {
            C= None
        }
    }
}

let testCSome ={
    A=Some {
        B=Some {
            C= Some 1000
        }
    }
}

let nestedmatch (t:test2) =  
    match t.A with
    |Some A ->
        match A.B with
        |Some B ->
            match B.C with
            |Some C ->printfn $"{C}"
            |_ -> printfn "None at C"
        |_ ->printfn "None at B"
    |_->printfn "None at A"
```

Answer (score 4):

Patterns can be *nested*, that's their whole power compared to the lame `if`/`then` construct of C, Java et al.

```
let nestedmatch (t:test2) =  
    match t with
    | { A = Some { B = Some { C = Some c } } } ->
        printfn $"{c}"
    | _ -> 
        printfn "Nope"
```

Comment: If it is not a record, but an instance of a class, and also has a nested option, can it still be done?

Comment: @nevermind_15, no, pattern matching is not for mutable classes, only records or DUs. You can use the `Option.map` approach or use FsToolkit's `option` CE.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Here's one that ensures all the print statements on the `None`-path as well, without nesting:

```
let nested (t: test2) =
    let absent x () = printfn "None at %s" x; None

    t.A
    |> Option.orElseWith (absent "A")
    |> Option.bind (fun x -> x.B)
    |> Option.orElseWith (absent "B")
    |> Option.map (fun x -> printfn $"{x.C}")
    |> Option.orElseWith (absent "C")
```

Tbh, this is still a lot of code, but you asked "without nesting" ;).

Now, normally in F#, we don't give much meaning to `None`. If it's `None`, we just ignore it, which makes it so powerful. If the `None` case needs more meaning, than perhaps a `Result` type is more suitable, which will contain the `Error` case until the end, but only the first error it encounters.

If it doesn't need much meaning, i.e. if you can ditch those `None` paths, it becomes very simple and no nesting again:

```
let nested (t: test2) =
    t.A
    |> Option.bind (fun x -> x.B)
    |> Option.iter (fun x -> printfn $"{x.C}")
```

PS: I see now you specifically wanted to use a pattern match. Anyway, consider this an alternative approach to pattern matching.

PPS: one other alternative is the `option` CE of `FsToolkit.Errorhandling`:

```
// the 'option' CE works like Option.bind:
option {
   let! a = t.A
   let! b = a.B
   let! c = b.C
   printfn $"{c}"
}
|> function 
| None -> printfn "Nothing"
| Some _ -> ()
```